# How to use rules_oci to run an image local via Docker?

Tags: docker, bazel, rules-oci

I want to use [rules_oci](https://github.com/bazel-contrib/rules_oci) to build a (docker) image that I can run locally as a container. Here is my try:

*WORKSPACE.bazel*:

```
load("@bazel_tools//tools/build_defs/repo:http.bzl", "http_archive")

#-------------------------------------------------------
# rules_oci
#-------------------------------------------------------

http_archive(
    name = "rules_oci",
    sha256 = "176e601d21d1151efd88b6b027a24e782493c5d623d8c6211c7767f306d655c8",
    strip_prefix = "rules_oci-1.2.0",
    url = "https://github.com/bazel-contrib/rules_oci/releases/download/v1.2.0/rules_oci-v1.2.0.tar.gz",
)

load("@rules_oci//oci:dependencies.bzl", "rules_oci_dependencies")

rules_oci_dependencies()

load("@rules_oci//oci:repositories.bzl", "LATEST_CRANE_VERSION", "LATEST_ZOT_VERSION", "oci_register_toolchains")

oci_register_toolchains(
    name = "oci",
    crane_version = LATEST_CRANE_VERSION,
)

load("@rules_oci//oci:pull.bzl", "oci_pull")

oci_pull(
    name = "ubuntu",
    digest = "sha256:67211c14fa74f070d27cc59d69a7fa9aeff8e28ea118ef3babc295a0428a6d21",
    image = "ubuntu",
    platforms = [
        "linux/arm64/v8",
        "linux/amd64",
    ],
)

#-------------------------------------------------------
# rules_pkg
#-------------------------------------------------------

load("@bazel_tools//tools/build_defs/repo:http.bzl", "http_archive")

http_archive(
    name = "rules_pkg",
    sha256 = "8f9ee2dc10c1ae514ee599a8b42ed99fa262b757058f65ad3c384289ff70c4b8",
    urls = [
        "https://mirror.bazel.build/github.com/bazelbuild/rules_pkg/releases/download/0.9.1/rules_pkg-0.9.1.tar.gz",
        "https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_pkg/releases/download/0.9.1/rules_pkg-0.9.1.tar.gz",
    ],
)

load("@rules_pkg//:deps.bzl", "rules_pkg_dependencies")

rules_pkg_dependencies()
```

*BUILD.bazel*:

```
load("@rules_oci//oci:defs.bzl", "oci_image",  "oci_tarball")
load("@rules_pkg//:pkg.bzl", "pkg_tar")

pkg_tar(
    name = "app",
    srcs = ["test.sh"],
)

oci_image(
    name = "image",
    base = "@ubuntu",
    cmd = ["test.sh"],
    tars = ["app.tar"],
)

oci_tarball(
    name = "tarball",
    image = ":image",
    repo_tags = ["vertexwahn/my_example:v0.0.1"],
)
```

*test.sh*:

```bash
echo "Hello World!"
```

*.bazelversion*:

```
6.3.2
```

If run:

```bash
# List all images
docker image ls
# Create an image
bazel run //:tarball
# Run docker container and delete it on quit
sudo docker run vertexwahn/my_example:v0.0.1
```

I get the following error:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: exec: "test.sh": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown.
```

Any ideas on how to solve this issue? I can also live with a bzlmod solution.

The code can also be found [here](https://github.com/Vertexwahn/BazelDemos/tree/main/intermediate/docker/rules_oci_demo).

Comment: add execute permission to your local executable file which was getting copied to docker container and was the entrypoint

Comment: @Ashok If I do `chmod +x test.sh` I get the same error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer provided above was mildly incorrect. Here is a full correction for BUILD.bazel:

```
load("@rules_oci//oci:defs.bzl", "oci_image", "oci_push", "oci_tarball")
load("@rules_pkg//:pkg.bzl", "pkg_tar")

pkg_tar(
    name = "app",
    srcs = ["test.sh"],
    mode = "0755",
    package_dir = "/usr/bin"
)

oci_image(
    name = "image",
    base = "@ubuntu",
    cmd = ["test.sh"],
    tars = [":app"],
)

oci_tarball(
    name = "tarball",
    image = ":image",
    repo_tags = ["vertexwahn/my_example:v0.0.1"],
)

oci_push(
    name = "push",
    image = ":image",
    remote_tags = ["v0.0.1"],
    repository = "vertexwahn/my_example",
)
```

And, for test.sh:

```
#!/usr/bin/sh

echo "Hello World!"
```

The previous answer struggled to get the execution working properly (path issue and stuff).

Note: you can use docker save to get the image in some kind of archive format and typically use mc (midnight commander) to navigate within the archive and the archive in the archive. You'll see that there is no /bin folder but only /usr/bin. Hence the fix. A shebang can't hurt, too...

Comment: True, using an absolute path is preferable. Upvoted. I have updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

`cmd = ["test.sh"],` means you are relying on the `$PATH` for that `test.sh` to be executed.
And... "`"test.sh": executable file not found in $PATH`".

You could try and place `test.sh` into a directory that is already in the container's `$PATH`, or explicitly provide a path when running the command.

If we assume the `/usr/bin` folder is in the `$PATH`, update your `BUILD.bazel` [`pkg_tar`](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/5.1.1/be/pkg.html#pkg_tar) with:

```
pkg_tar(
    name = "app",
    srcs = ["test.sh"],
    mode = "0755",  # Make sure it is executable
    package_dir = "/usr/bin",  # That will place test.sh into a '/usr/bin' directory in the tarball
)

oci_image(
    name = "image",
    base = "@ubuntu",
    cmd = ["/usr/bin/test.sh"],  # Adjust the cmd to use the script from the '/usr/bin' directory
    tars = [":app"],  # Correcting this to use the label of the pkg_tar rule
)
```

And, from the comments, adds a [shebang line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) to `test.sh`:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/shshebang

echo "Hello World!"
```

Comment: Change my code as suggested by you - now I get an `exec bin/test.sh: exec format error` when I run `docker run vertexwahn/my_example:v0.0.1`

Comment: @Vertexwahn Can you make sure it is executable (`chmod +x test.sh`) and add a `#!/bin/bash` (shebang line) as first line of `test.sh`?

Comment: @Vertexwahn I have updated the answer to use an absolute path, and to include the shebang line I mentioned in my previous command.